Getting dynamic application log file name based on podId of a containerised application
I am having an containerised application with 1 container. In that container I have multiple pods.
For simplicity let's take 3 pods. POD1 (with pod id as pd1), POD2 (pd2), POD3 (pd3)
In the log4j.yml file I have configured the app log files as:
fileName: "logs/app.log"
What it do is it generates app.log file in every instance of the pod in that container.

POD1 -> in logs directory app.log is present
POD2 -> in logs directory app.log is present
POD3 -> in logs directory app.log is present

But I want the files to be like:

POD1 -> in logs directory we should have app_pd1.log
POD2 -> in logs directory we should have app_pd2.log
POD3 -> in logs directory we should have app_pd3.log

What I tried:
As mentioned in Log4j Kubernetes Support
I tried fileName: "logs/app_${k8s:podId}.log"
But it didn't worked, The file was made with static name as app_${k8s:podId}.log in all the pods.

Getting files out of containers is hard.  Can you remove this fileName: setting and have your application log to stdout?  Then kubectl logs and log-management systems that support the Kubernetes logging framework would be able to pick them up, without worrying about what filename specifically you're using.

@DavidMaze This might work but this is not an option for me. I need to change the file names in the pod dynamically (preferably by adding pod Ids). All the pods are sending the app.log file to fluent bit. As the file name is same so all the files are getting overwritten from different pods and I am able see the logs of just 1 pod (the last read pod file) on Open Search. To distinguish between the different pod files I have to add an identifier to the file name. So that all the logs are send to opensearch. I hope I am able to explain the problem here.

log4j-kubernetes requires access to the Kubernetes API. See Configuring kubernetes-client for more details. BTW: log4j-kubernetes is deprecated in favor of kubernetes-log4j.

@PiotrP.Karwasz As I mentioned in the question that I tried using that format as addressed in the doc. But I am still not able to access the podId. I have 2 questions here.

Can we access podId using log4j.
if Yes, then what's the way.

If we can't then how can we change the name of the application log file generated by each pod. (every pod should generate a different log file name)

@Pavittar, could you share your log4j2.yml and pom.xml files and the output of your application run with the -Dlog4j2.debug JVM argument, please? (Note that the Log4j configuration file naming is very important: log4j.yml != log4j2.yml.)
